# SQL add new column to view table on condition

Tags: sql-server

I'm not sure if it's possible but I need to create a view table with dynamically added columns. Lets say I have this table myDB.tblSpecificConsideration with the following data:

```
InqryID | Blue  | Red  | Yellow
-----------------------------
1       | False | True | True
```

And I have my code for this view table:

```
SELECT
  myDB.tblSpecificConsideration.blue,
  myDB.tblSpecificConsideration.red,
  myDB.tblSpecificConsideration.yellow, 
CASE 
  WHEN myDB.tblSpecificConsideration.red = 'TRUE' then 'Red' 
  WHEN myDB.tblSpecificConsideration.blue = 'TRUE' then 'Blue' 
END AS STATUS
FROM myDB.tblSpecificConsideration
```

So here is my question, is it possible to show column just if the value is True, and let say if Red and Blue are both TRUE, to have two columns, STATUS1 with value Red, STATUS2 with value blue.

Thanks.

Comment: In plain SQL hiding columns from the output based on their input values (conditions) is not possible. Also, look into `sql aliases` as it will save you some typing.

Comment: What happens if InqryID 2 has True for all 3?  Wouldn't you still show the Blue column for 1 since it was True for 2?

Comment: So, for 1, you show Red and Yellow.  But, if 2 is True for Blue, aren't you now showing all 3 columns?

Comment: At first I was going to say Dynamic SQL, but you should just use a switch/ case statement so that only one query runs. This way you limit the impact on database and make the code simple to manage. Dynamic SQL is dangerous anyways, though this still could be implemented in small code. Just depends on the risk or complexity of the query.

Comment: The genius of this is you can handle improper requests dynamically as well (I.e. if a expression would result in an empty query). Another way of saying is you would only need to test the conditions that necessitates a given query, making management simple